# Why don't we teach slang in schools?

Tags: vocabulary, slang

The English language is always evolving, and current day slang will soon become mainstream, just as much our current vocabulary originated as slang. If so, then why is it is writing/speaking slang discouraged in many US schools?

Comment: One obvious reason is that whereas [ninety percent of everything is crap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_Law), that proportion rises significantly higher in the case of ***slang***. With the inevitable result that by the time you reach my age, most of the slang you learnt in your schooldays (not in formal classes, obviously), has now been consigned to the dustbin of history. Another obvious reason is that young people are already effectively "pre-programmed" to actually *seek out* slang without needing (expensive) encouragement from teachers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, but why would it be *discouraged*?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 Because slang is **by definition** non-standard. Its function is to identify the speaker as a member of a narrow ethnic or age-based community, while what is taught in school is facility in reading, writing and speaking the language of the academic, scientific and professional communities.

Comment: There is some slang which is so well established, it becomes the duty of any self respecting language teacher to at least mention and indicate its use to students learning the English language. Such as: booze; chat up; cop; copper; loaded; yank; etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't want my kids being taught your last example in school (I don't remember that class though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fumble Fingers said, people learn slang naturally; it does not need to be taught in schools, which have a large enough responsibility to teach valid subjects, such as history, mathematics, science, social studies, foreign languages, etc.

Also, slang changes very quickly, whereas **idioms** do not. For this reason, *idioms* are covered in schools, for the purpose of cultural literacy. Slang is more related to cultural illiteracy.

If you want to explore the [purpose of school](http://www.purposeofschool.com/), please do.

Comment: In addition, one goal of school is to teach people to communicate in a professional, formal manner. We rarely learn that from our natural environments as children, but we often need it in our daily lives as adults. I suspect that’s rather a big part of why schools forego teaching slang and vernaculars and instead focus on standardised and not necessarily altogether _natural_ language use.